# cakephp count associated data

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Im trying to count the associated data of items.

"Feeds"
"Feed_Likes" (Foreign Key Feed_id)
"User_Feedhistorys" (Foreign Key Feed_id)

The "User_Feedhistorys" table contains a list of usernames and Feed_id's of "viewed" feeds.

The Feed_Likes table contains a Feed_id and the username who liked the feed.

Id like to count the "Feed_likes" of each feed in the feed table and count the umber of entries in the "User_Feedhistorys" table for each feed.

Ive read the manual many times and im stuck. I cant get one of the items counted and returned as a virtual field but not both. How can i combine the below or re-write the function to work as indeded.

The below function only gets one or the other, can you help please?

```
public function findFeedViewCount(Query $query, array $options){        

        /*return $query = $this->find()
            ->select(['view_count' => $query->func()->count('UserFeedhistorys.feed_id')])           
            ->leftJoinWith('UserFeedhistorys')
            ->group(['Feeds.id'])
            ->contain(['FeedCategories', 'FeedOwners','UserFeedsubscriptions','FeedLikes','UserFeedhistorys'])          
            ->autoFields(true);*/

        return $query = $this->find()
            ->select(['like_count' => $query->func()->count('FeedLikes.feed_id')])          
            ->leftJoinWith('FeedLikes')
            ->group(['Feeds.id'])
            ->contain(['FeedCategories', 'FeedOwners','UserFeedsubscriptions','FeedLikes','UserFeedhistorys'])          
            ->autoFields(true);

    }
```